# Mathematica Kernel Aborting With ComplexPlot

Tags: plotting, complex, animation, kernel, abort

I am trying to run the following line:

```
Animate[ComplexPlot[Zeta[z + t], {z, -3 (1 + I), 3 (1 + I)}, 
  ColorFunction -> "CyclicReImLogAbs"], {t, 0, 1}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

In Mathematica 12.2, but it unfortunately I just get `$Aborted`:

[image]

Is there some way to prevent this?

Comment: Runs in MMA version 12.1

Comment: It aborted on my machine with 12.1.  However, how about setting the decrement dt such as {t,0,1,1/10}.  This way it does not abort.  Or you could generate 100 plots in a table with dt=1/100 separately then Animate or Manipulate the table of plots.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify a higher timeout for the kernel so it doesn't abort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Do not do computations inside the [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) unless absolutely necessary.

```
plts = Table[ComplexPlot[Zeta[z + t],
    {z, -3 (1 + I), 3 (1 + I)},
    ColorFunction -> "CyclicReImLogAbs",
    MaxRecursion -> 5],
   {t, 0, 1, 0.025}];
```

With pre-computed images the animation runs smoothly.

```
Animate[plts[[n]], {n, 1, Length[plts], 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]